# Hbase shell get this error:fstat unimplemented unsupported or native support failed to load

Tags: python, hadoop, hbase, alpine-linux

I was trying to install on alpine vm.
I followed the tutorial here https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-a-standalone-hbase-local-instance-and-connect-to-it-with-python-happybase-9751c9fe6941

I got error below:

```
alpine:/home/downloads/hbase-2.2.3# ./bin/hbase shell
2020-04-02 23:34:53,255 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
HBase Shell
Use "help" to get list of supported commands.
Use "exit" to quit this interactive shell.
For Reference, please visit: http://hbase.apache.org/2.0/book.html#shell
Version 2.2.3, r6a830d87542b766bd3dc4cfdee28655f62de3974, 2020年 01月 10日 星期五 18:27:51 CST
Took 0.0160 seconds
NotImplementedError: fstat unimplemented unsupported or native support failed to load; see http://wiki.jruby.org/Native-Libraries
  initialize at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1013
        open at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1154
  initialize at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb/input-method.rb:141
  initialize at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb/context.rb:70
  initialize at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb.rb:426
  initialize at /home/downloads/hbase-2.2.3/lib/ruby/irb/hirb.rb:47
       start at /home/downloads/hbase-2.2.3/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:207
      <main> at /home/downloads/hbase-2.2.3/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:219
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: I saw a post from https://github.com/HariSekhon/Dockerfiles/issues/33, but have no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer
need to install additional package.

```
sudo apt-get install jruby -y
sudo apt-get install asciidoctor -y
```

Comment: Thanks!!, This solution worked for me with alpine image
`apk add jruby && apk add asciidoctor`